# Flash - RemoveChild Actionscript 3 dont work delete

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I made a game that is based on collecting stars. I have a problem that is at the moment of meeting 4 stars want to share passed to the next frame and removed all the frames tried `removeChild()` but a message pops up :

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

```
health_txt.text=health.toString()
score_txt.text=score.toString();
var health=20; 
var score=0;
var intervalPunkty = setInterval(addGwiazda,1000);

function addGwiazda()
{
    var gwiazda:Gwiazda = new Gwiazda();
    gwiazda.x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 550);
    gwiazda.y = -50;
    addChild(gwiazda);
    gwiazda.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dropGwiazda);

    function dropGwiazda(e:Event)
    {
        var b:Gwiazda = Gwiazda(e.target);
        b.y += 10;
        if(b.y > 400)
        {
            b.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dropGwiazda);
            removeChild(b);
        }
        if(jazda.hitTestObject(b))
        {
            score ++;
            score_txt.text = score.toString();
            b.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dropGwiazda);
            removeChild(b);
            if (score == 4){
                gotoAndStop(15);
                removeChild(b);
            }
        }
    }

}

stop();
```

Comment: You're trying to manipulate a property of an object which doesn't exist.

Comment: What should I do to make the code work?

Comment: you use "removeChild(b)" more than once then it's probebly trigered more than once. Trace out this part to check how many times it's removed.

Comment: I think that your problem is coming from this line : `if(jazda.hitTestObject(b))` because after going to the 15th frame, the `jazda` object didn't exist there and you got that error, also don't forget to clear your `intervalPunkty ` interval ...

Answer (score 0):

```
score_txt.text=score.toString();
var health=20; 
var score=0;
var intervalPunkty = setInterval(addGwiazda,1000);

function addGwiazda()
{
    var gwiazda:Gwiazda = new Gwiazda();
    gwiazda.x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 550);
    gwiazda.y = -50;
    addChild(gwiazda);
    gwiazda.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dropGwiazda);

    function dropGwiazda(e:Event)
    {
        var b:Gwiazda = Gwiazda(e.target);
        b.y += 10;
        if(b.y > 400)
        {
            b.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dropGwiazda);
            if(contains(b))
            {
              removeChild(b);
            }
        }
        if(jazda.hitTestObject(b))
        {
            score ++;
            score_txt.text = score.toString();
            b.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dropGwiazda);
            if(contains(b))
            {
              removeChild(b);
            }
            if (score == 4){
                gotoAndStop(15);

            }
        }
    }

}

stop();`enter code here`
```